# Plot HDR tonemap curves

Tags: hdr

I am using a tonemapper in our project and a friend of mine asked if I could provide him with a plot of the tonemapper used (different functions are implemented). I tried in MATLAB to copy the tone-mapper function and use luma values from -5 to 5.0 to feed to the function, but the resulting plot is nothing like a classic tonemap function plot as I happen to see around. The function is totally correct, but am I missing something stupid that must be taken into account when trying to plot them?

Comment: You asking for help without showing code nor results, seriously? Are you sure thats even gamedev topic?

Comment: @KromStern I can show results, but they're clearly wrong as I can show code, but is nothing more than what I described. What's the problem with this, isn't posting such code redundant? Also, it is a quite general question, to post generalized code it means to post three lines of MATLAB code. About the question about the "on-topicness" of the post, well, I figured that as HDR is used a lot in games, plotting something useful to the understanding of the tone mapping process could be related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luma values should always be positive. You might be confusing it with log-luminance. A lot of these plots are shown with a log scale for the x axis. On a log scale you can see the characteristic "S curve", while on a scale whose x axis is linear luminance, it doesn't look like an S.

For example, my favorite tone curve is [Jim Hejl's curve as reported by John Hable](http://www.slideshare.net/ozlael/hable-john-uncharted2-hdr-lighting/140), used in Infamous Second Son and probably other games.  Here's what the curve looks like in linear space (i.e. just graphing the equation on that slide):

[image]

Here's what it looks like if I convert the x-axis to a log scale (in other words, replace x by 2^x in the equation, so that x is now the log2 of luminance):

[image]

Now that looks more like the S-curve that I guess you were probably looking for.  [Here are the equations on Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ct9g0epdte) if you want to play around with them.